# ISSUE with Transparent navbar to visible when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem with this code. Everything works perfectly(nav has no color and after I start scrolling the background begin to get color) except that when I enter the site the background is Black and after first scroll it becomes transparent. If I go around the page is works perfectly except when I enter the page.

CSS

```
#header1 {  
   background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);   
   width:100%;
   height:45px;
   position: fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0px;
   z-index:9100;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header1"></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
$('#header1').css('opacity', ($(document).scrollTop() / 500));
});
```

Comment: add `opacity:0` to the CSS ... when you enter the site your header has no opaciry specified so by default it's `1` --> so it's visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the initial opacity to 0 in your CSS.

Anyway, bear in mind opacity applies not only to the div, but all it's contents. Which is not really what you want 99% of the times...

Comment: I cloned the DIV, so the DIV with the content its with transparent background, and I created the same Div with the same properties, but empy so I can play with it's background. And This worked! I figured it out 3 right before you answered, but Thank you!

Comment: wait... that's what I meant actually. If you want to change the background, use the alpha channel on your rgba background declaration (fourth argument), not the opacity property.